# Zeros of this multivariate polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I have an equation, wich is somewhat related to the doppler effect :

$$
x_1^2x_3^2+x_2^2x_4^2+2x_1x_2x_3x_4-Cx_1^2-Cx_2^2=0
$$
Where C is a known real positive constant.

My background in math isn't really strong (I'm a signal processing engineer), so i'm unable to make any practical use of the algebraic geometry resources I've found.

I would like to gain some insight on this equation. Does it fall into any classification, for instance a conic ? If not, what can I know about the solutions of this equation ? If this make no sense : what can I ask about the solutions ?

Thanks,

Antoine.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify (since $C$ is known) whether $C\gt 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can simplify the solutions by noticing that if points $(x_1,x_2)$ satisfy:

$$ x_1^2 + x_2^2 = R $$

then the main equation can be rewritten:

$$ (x_1x_3 + x_2x_4)^2 = CR $$

So an approach is to pick values for $x_1,x_2$ and then solve the latter for $x_3,x_4$.  The solutions are not unique, but since you have one equation and four unknowns, this is to be expected.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've used it successfully. Picking values for x3 and x4 instead of x1 and x2 as I have an additionnal constraint on x3 and x4